# Can a Parse account be protected from targeted rate-limit attack?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using Parse as a cloud-database in my project (along with some server-type functions, such as for data validation). When my project is released, it may be controversial. Since the Parse burst rate-limit for queries is 40 requests per second, I'm worried someone will extract the API key and set up a computer to make 40 login or "create account" requests per second. They could even launch 40 copies of the app per second in emulators.

If this happens, is there anything at all we can do to continue using Parse? It seems like an almost-zero-effort DOS method, and everyone that uses Parse is vulnerable. If this occurs, can we do anything like block IP ranges? Do we have any recourse? Buying a bigger plan does not prevent this attack.

Comment: No. You can't stop this sort of attack with Parse.com functionality alone. What you _could_ do is set up a proxy that manages the load towards parse, and you could put filter rules for IP ranges in there. You'll also need to direct all the app traffic through your proxy and because of this you probably can't use the ParseSDK in your project, so you'll need to write your own API/SDK for your proxy.